# Are there any high quality professional 1/4” jack headphones?

Tags: headphones

Most headphones on the market sport an adapter to convert to 1/4”. I’m looking for headphones that are just 1/4” and don’t need an adapter.

Answer (score 2):

These days, those are going to be rare because so many sources have 3.5mm sockets. If you insist on having a 1/4" connector instead of an adapter, cut off the existing connector and solder in a 1/4" connector in its place. Neutrik makes nice high-quality 1/4" connectors.

On high-quality headphones, the adapter is not an issue. It screws on securely (e.g. Sennheiser do this) so the 3.5 mm pin can't move around in the barrel.

Answer (score 0):

The connector is not an important factor when choosing headphones. What matters is that the headphones are well-matched physically and aurally to your head and ears. If you don't like the connector, get a repair shop to re-terminate it to your preferred connector.